# edge connectivity of a unicyclic graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-connectivity

How would you show that the edge connectivity for a uni-cyclic graph is no greater than 2?

I've tried to draw a few graphs first to see how I should approach it but not sure how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a uni-cyclic graph:

[image]

You can delete any single edge and the remaining graph remains connected but if you delete two non-adjacent edges, the graph is no longer connected.

Here is another uni-cyclic graph:

[image]

You can find single edges (along the arms, for instance) that, when deleted, make the remaining graph non-connected.  But you problem statement implies *all* uni-cyclic graphs, so it must hold for the above graph.